# Why does two recaptcha appear at one moment in time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, recaptcha, captcha

I have two forms in modal windows on one page (authorization and registration). For both forms, I connect an invisible recaptcha (v2). Here is code of recaptcha init:

```
var idCaptcha1, idCaptcha2;
var onloadReCaptchaInvisible = function () {
    //login
    idCaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
        "sitekey": "6LfpltgUAAAAAMW3PstNGrEk3pMos0TzN9jyL7mT",
        "callback": "onSubmitReCaptcha1",
        "size": "invisible"
    });
    //reg
    idCaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
        "sitekey": "6LfpltgUAAAAAMW3PstNGrEk3pMos0TzN9jyL7mT",
        "callback": "onSubmitReCaptcha2",
        "size": "invisible"
    });
};

function onSubmitReCaptcha1(token) {
    alert('test');
    sendForm('signin', idCaptcha1);
}

function onSubmitReCaptcha2(token) {
    sendForm('signup', idCaptcha2);
}
```

When user submit any form, I try to find out whats form exctly, and execute captcha I need:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    // отменим отправку форму на сервер
    event.preventDefault();

    switch($(this).closest('.modal').attr('id')){
        case 'signin':
            grecaptcha.execute(idCaptcha1);
        case 'signup':
            grecaptcha.execute(idCaptcha2);
    }

});
```

Finally, this is the code of sending form function:

```
function sendForm(id,captcha){
    alert(id);
    let form = $('#'+id).find('form'),
        url  = form.attr('action'),
        formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append('g-recaptcha-response', grecaptcha.getResponse(captcha));

    console.log(url);    
    console.log(formData);        
}
```

So, captchas work fine, besides fact both of them appear at once. What I did wrong?
I suspect problem in `$('form').submit()` but I cant find out reason.

[image: I attached the screenshot.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `break` statement at the end of each `case`. If you match the first case and don't have `break`, it falls through and executes the next case, so both recaptchas are shown.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    // отменим отправку форму на сервер
    event.preventDefault();

    switch($(this).closest('.modal').attr('id')){
        case 'signin':
            grecaptcha.execute(idCaptcha1);
            break;
        case 'signup':
            grecaptcha.execute(idCaptcha2);
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Damn, I made so childish mistake >< Thank u sir!